# Seismic disrupters

Tags: star-wars

I do not understand why when Jengo Fett launched a missile in space at Obi Wan there was an audible sound when it exploded. It was a cool sound effect but,there would be no atmosphere to cause any sound. The expanding blast ring shape as opposed to an expanding spherical blast may have been because it was designed to explode in a 2-D plane. The energy of the blast seems very powerful which may because all the energy is redirected and forced in one plane, like a bullet's speed and force is because the barrel of the gun forces all the energy of the chamber explosion in one direction. The ring plane blast may also been designed not because of need to redirect energy of the blast to make it more powerful,but as a safety precaution for the space ship launching it from being also vaporized.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in here or are you just wanting to point out the difference between hard science-fiction (e.g. 2001: A Space Odyssey) and Sci-fantasy (e.g. Star Wars)?

Answer (score 3):

Explosions in space is one of the biggest and most egregious example of bad science in science fiction, enough so that it has its own TVTropes page, [Explosions in Space](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExplosionsInSpace), a specific example of [Space Does Not Work That Way.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceDoesNotWorkThatWay)

In any but the hardest of science fiction, no real effort is done to represent space realistically, even more so than other speculative science things, but space is so huge, it's hard for us to reason about it. So we invent hyperdrive or jumpgates to deal with the huge scale, and we gloss over the effects of zero-g on various things - and all that is common in much "harder" science fiction than Star Wars, which uses the "long time ago, far far away" line to get away with almost anything.

I wouldn't try to rationalize it. Some things can be worked into a semblance of coherent realism, but I don't think that explosions in space can.

Comment: Think it's also important to mention that in some instances creators try to fight that common trope. For example, Battlestar Galactica (reimagined) did a great job in my opinion by dampening all sound during space scenes. With it completely missing it might be more realistic/accurate, but far less enjoyable; maybe even disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to talk about that space battle, you see Jango and Kenobi twisting and doing acrobatic flying stunts while in space! To "bank" a turn, jets use properties like air resistance, wind, and even friction, none of which are present in a vacuum; so, no turning and flying cool, no explosions, and definitely no sound would EVER be possible in space. If that doesn't show you that Lucas wasn't really trying to accurately rep space physics then I don't know what would.